# I need complete tutorial about how make load balancing at ASP.net 4.0 Web server

Tags: load, webserver, asp.net-4.0, load-balancing, web-farm

I want to make load balancing at my server. My current configuration:

- web application is netframework 4.0
- running on 1 vps

  sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="60"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your VPS is not enough perhaps start there, get a dedicated server.

Then when you really need more power; load balancing will require multiple servers ;-)

You're use a session state service, which is good if you need session state across a web farm. It's currently pointing to localhost though, you'd need to configure an IP accessible by all machines in the farm.

For the rest web farming is kind of a broad topic, a lot depends on your type of application also.

Comment: thanks for comment. well i was asking this because per vps maximum supports 4 core. so if i distribute it to 2 vps it will be supporting 8 core at total :) well next month i am planing to buy either vps or certainly do this load balancing. my current provider said that your vpses already using too much cpu :)  bu i still need complete tutorial. i also searched and find that i need to do network load balancing am i right ?